# Compact set of "symmetric difference metric space"

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, set-theory, compactness, hausdorff-distance

**Problem:** Show that $I(A)$ is not compact in $(X, \delta)$.

Let $X$ be a set of convex polygons in a plane, and for all $A \in X$, $m(A)$ denotes the area of $A$.
We define a distance function on $X$ by
$$\delta(A,B) = m((A \cup B) - (A \cap B))$$ for $A, B \in X$. If we use the notation $\triangle$ as the symmetric difference of $A$ and $B$, we can write $\delta(A, B) = m(A \triangle B)$.
I checked $\delta$ is exactly a distance function on $X$. Therefore $(X, \delta)$ be a metric space.

For $A \in X$, define $I(A) = \{ E \in X \hspace{1mm}| \hspace{1mm} E \subset A\}$. I want prove $I(A)$ is not compact in $(X, \delta)$.

Actually I also proved that $m : X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous on $X$, thus I tried 2 ways to prove this problem but both didn't work:

1. If $I(A)$ is compact in $X$, $m(I(A))$ should be also compact in $\mathbb{R}$, but it is obviously $m(I(A)) = [0, m(A)]$ because we can choose an(or more) appropriate subset $E$ of $A$, which satisfies $m(E) = y$, for any $y \in [0, m(A)]$. Thus I couldn't get anything from this approach.
2. If $I(A)$ is compact in $X$, because $X$ is a hausdorff space, $I(A)$ is closed in $X$. Thus I tried to lead a contradiction from here(e.g., $I(A)$ is not closed in $X$), but I couldn't. Because $X$ is a metric space, I can write the definition of open sets in $X$ precisely:
   $$U \subset X \hspace{1mm} \text{is open} \Leftrightarrow \hspace{1mm} \text{For any} \hspace{1mm} u \in U,\hspace{1mm} \text{there exists} \hspace{1mm} \varepsilon >0 \hspace{1mm} \text{satisfies} \hspace{1mm} B(x, \varepsilon) \subset U$$
   Where $B$ is a open ball in $X$. But it looks there is no contradiction in this approach, too.

I don't know what I should do next. How can I show the first statement?

Comment: When you say convex polygons, do you mean sets defined by finite intersections of half spaces? Do you allow for $\mathbb{R}^2$ to be a convex polygon?

Comment: Also, do you disallow points to be convex polygons?

Comment: The original text said nothing about convex polygons so I'm not sure, but I think its definition is, "the line segment between two points of the polygon is contained in the union of the interior and the boundary of the polygon. In particular, it is a simple polygon (not self-intersecting)." I quoted from Wikipedia:[link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_polygon)

Comment: And from the definition, $\mathbb{R}^2$ and points are not included in $X$ I guess.

Comment: So, is the polygon just the edges or the also the enclosed interior? Because I would say the are of a polygon without the interior is $0$. This would also mean that $\delta\equiv 0$, if you don't include the interior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try at an answer, given what you commented so far.

Since $X$ does not contain points, I would say that you can find a Cauchy sequence of convex polygons whose limit is not a convex polygon.

Take a fixed convex polygon $A_0\in X$ with $m(A_0)>0$.  Find a sequence of convex polygons, $\{ B_n\}\in I(A_0) $ , such that $\text{diam}(B_n)\to 0$. You can find  a subsequence of nested convex polygons $\{ B_{n_k} \}$, since $A_0$ is compact.

By Cantor's intersection theorem, there exists a $p\in \text{int}(A_0)$ such that $\cap_{k}B_{n_k}=\{p \}$. For $k_2> k_1$, we have that $\delta( B_{n_{k_1}},B_{n_{k_2}} )= m( B_{n_{k_1}} )\leq \pi \big(\text{diam}(B_{n_{k_1}}) \big)^2 \overset{k_1\to \infty}{\to}0$.

Since, by what you said, any convex polygon will have non-negative area it follows that there is no limit to the subsequence.

I've skipped some details because I thought they would be tedious. I think you also need to clarify some details about $X$. Namely, is $X$ the set of all convex polygons, and is $I(A_0)$ infinite. I think that this probably the direction to show non-compactness.

Comment: Thank you for answering my problem, But I need some time to understand your answer(I've never heard Cantor's intersection theorem). I'll think about it in your way. Thank you.